# easy way to create a file nested in unavailable directories

Tags: linux, command-line

I know I can do

```
mdkir -p a/b/c/d
```

However time and again I need to put a file in a new directory. So this is what I do

```
mkdir -p a/b/c
touch a/b/c/foo.txt
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to combine those two operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Bash shell, create a function in your .bashrc file.

```
function mktouch {
  mkdir -p $( dirname $1 )
  touch $1
}
```

Then just call  mktouch a/b/c/foo.txt

Answer (score 1):

In bash you could do:

```
 mkdir -p a/b/c && touch !#:2/foo.txt
```

But that's not exactly as terse as I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on Steve K's answer, if the path has spaces in it, it won't work as expected,

```
mktouch a/b\ b/c/d.txt
mkdir: created directory 'a'
mkdir: created directory 'a/b'
touch: cannot touch 'a/b b/c/d.txt': No such file or directory
```

Double quotes will prevent word splitting.

```
function mktouch {
    mkdir -p "$( dirname "$1" )"
    touch "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fish shell:

```
function mktouch
  mkdir -p $( dirname $argv[1] )
  touch $argv[1]
end
```

mktouch a/b/c/foo.txt